# Click on Button Class or Span class

Tags: javascript, class, button, click

I want to simulate a click on a button up or down,

I tried with this :`document.querySelector('button.up')[4].click();`

in the page there is few input field with up and down button, I would like the button up of the field with id "sl" or nth up button ? 
the code :

```
<div class="input-text num" >
<input type="text" placeholder="" id="sl" min="0" max="" step="0.00001">
<button tabindex="-1" class="up">
<span class="v"></span></button><
button tabindex="-1" class="down">
<span class="v"></span></button></div>
```

Comment: sl is the id of the input fiel, but on the side there is up and down button

Comment: there is few others input field with up and down button, I would like to click on the up button of the sl input

Comment: I edited the question thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that's likely to cause a problem is this line:

```
document.querySelector('button.up')[4].click();
```

The reasons this causes a problem is that `document.querySelector()` returns either the first element matching the supplied selector or `null`, if there are no elements matching the selector. Therefore index notation the `[4]` is destined to fail by design.

Without seeing more of your HTML it's hard to offer a fully working suggestion, but I'd suggest that using an alternative selector should work (so long as your `id` attributes are unique, as they must be be according to the spec):

```
document.querySelector('#sl + button.up').click();
```

```js
const clickHandler = (event) => {
  console.log(`${event.target.outerHTML}`);
}

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(
  (button) => button.addEventListener('click', clickHandler)
);

document.querySelector('#sl + button.up').click();
```

```html
<div class="input-text num">
  <input type="text" placeholder="" id="sl" min="0" max="" step="0.00001">
  <button tabindex="-1" class="up">
<span class="v">up</span></button>
  <button tabindex="-1" class="down">
    <span class="v">down</span></button>
</div>
```

References:

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`HTMLElement.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: "*Without seeing *more* of your HTML*" not "*Without seeing *all* of your HTML*" - code should always be reduced to the "*[mcve]*" principle, and posted *in* your question rather than (only) linking to it.

Comment: thank you, the code I showed it's not all, I thought it will be enough, the rest of the code is same but with different id and field, one after one

Comment: I tried this : document.querySelector('#sl + button.up').click();
and it doesn't work may it work with span.v  instead of button..up ?

Comment: "*and it doesn't work*"  - I have no idea. Post your **[mcve]*" HTML in your question and maybe we can see why it's not working. You may also need to read the "*[ask]*" guidelines before you edit your question.